# Where are Freemarker Functions set?

Tags: freemarker

I have not used Freemarker before and inherited some templates that won't compile.  I have narrowed down the line that is causing problems to:

```
${text('Text and {0}', 'More Text')}
```

Where does this text() function come from?  I understand that its trying to return the second string injected into the first like: "Text and More Text".

Here is the error:

```
FreeMarker template error:
For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to an extended_hash (wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash):
```

modernizr-2.6.2.js is the only javascript imported.

Any ideas why this line is causing problems and where this function should be declared??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can come from a few places:

- From the data-model (one of the parameters you pass to `Template.process`)
- From a shared variable, which is added to the `Configuration` singleton.
- From an `#include`-d template (or from the template you are in), via `#function text` or `#assign text = ...` (or `#global text = ...`)
- From an `#import`-ed template via `#global text = ...` (highly unlikely...)

But one potentially interesting thing is that the error says that `text` does exist, but it's a hash (a `Map`-like thing), not a callable thing. Maybe something that's also called `text` shadows the good `text`? What does `${.data_model.text('Text and {0}', 'More Text')}` say?

You mention a JavaScript file. FreeMarker has nothing to do with JavaScript (and it runs on the server, inside the JVM).

Comment: Your answer lead me on the right direction.  Basically I can create a text() by implementing TemplateMethodModelEx then putting that class in the data-model (which for my case was a hash-map), which was your first bullet point.  Reference: http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateMethodModelEx.html